# Copy database from host with MongoDB 2.4 to host with MongoDB 3.0 via ssh tunnel

Tags: mongodb, ssh

I trying to migrate an old application, using MongoDB 2.4 to a host, running MongoDB 3.0 in Docker container. For test purpose I am copying the data via ssh tunnel from the older to the newer version.

As I read about the updating process of MongoDB, first I should use Mongo 2.6 and then 3.0. However my test with avoiding the step with version 2.6 was successful and the database works fine. Could somebody explain me is that really possible or I have misunderstood something? It's really strange for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from 2.4 to 2.6, prior to upgrading to 3.0 is a requirement according to the documentation:

> To upgrade an existing MongoDB deployment to 3.0, you must be running
>   2.6. If you’re running a version of MongoDB before 2.6, you must upgrade to 2.6 before upgrading to 3.0. See Upgrade to 2.6 for the
>   procedure to upgrade from 2.4 to 2.6. Once upgraded to MongoDB 2.6,
>   you cannot downgrade to any version earlier than MongoDB 2.4.

Having said that, if you have run the corresponding test cases for your application, with a good test coverage,  the indexes are working properly, and nothing has been broken I can not see a reason to worry about but ideally they suggest to migrate to 2.6 and then make the move to 3.0 to avoid data corruption.